# Error "CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point" when built by "dotnet.exe"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, azure-pipelines, dotnet-cli

I was create a azure pipeline to run unit test for a net project.

Here is the doc I followed.

https://build5nines.com/azure-pipeline-publish-unit-test-and-code-coverage-results-with-net-solution-using-vstest-cobertura-and-coverlet/

Here is the pipeline:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  

trigger: none

pool: 'Windows2022'

variables:
  buildPlatform: 'x64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: Dependency

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1


- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '7.x'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build the project - Release'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--no-restore --configuration Release'
    projects: 'HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'restore'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    arguments: '--no-build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    workingDirectory: 'HPCEMConnectionWizardWin\HPCEMConnectionWizardWin'
```

error when built with command "dotnet.exe build":

2023-06-29T08:13:47.1547657Z ##[error]CSC(0,0): Error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
2023-06-29T08:13:47.1564704Z CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [C:\agent_work\3\s\HPCEMConnectionWizardWin\HPCEMConnectionWizardWin\HPCEMConnectionWizardWin.csproj]

And the same project can be built sucessfully using following task using MSBuild:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'HPCEMConnectionWizardWin\HPCEMConnectionWizardWin.sln'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

How shouldd I resolve this error? such as add something into the project file.

I was trying to run the unit tests within solution using command "dotnet.exe test", so I have to build the project using command "dotnet.exe build"? can I use VSBuild task to build it, than run the unit tests using command "dotnet.exe test"?

build log:
[build log](https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=B195f95ea18b845899cfbcdc41d76428e638239618565142903_dev.azure.com_hpcodeway_806ecdbd-12ca-4382-bb72-c6524f7cb1a3__apis_build_builds_3317423_logs_13.txt&tid=195f95ea18b845899cfbcdc41d76428e638239618565142903)

project file:
[project file](https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=Bdd29b203cc1c4c4bb68d9fa3272ae32b638239620303562778_HPCEMConnectionWizardWin.csproj&tid=dd29b203cc1c4c4bb68d9fa3272ae32b638239620303562778)

Comment: Why are you restoring and building a single project, then restoring and building the solution? The MSBuild version only shows the solution.

Comment: Here is the example I referenced.  
https://build5nines.com/azure-pipeline-publish-unit-test-and-code-coverage-results-with-net-solution-using-vstest-cobertura-and-coverlet/

if I build "**/*.csproj" or "**/*.sln" using "dotnet.exe build", Error "CS5001" is still there, and just add more errors from other two sub projects written in C++.
HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin/HPCEMConnectionWizardWin.csproj is the main project written in C#.